# How to retry DynamoDb write when throttled?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write large amounts of data to dynamo using AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient and I am trying to understand what the best practice of handling throttling is?

For example, I have a capacity of 3000 writes and at a given moment I have, let's say, 100,000 records I'd like to write.  I don't need them all in immediately, but I am trying to figure what the best way to get them in is.

This application is running in a distributed environment so there maybe 5 executors all trying to do this at the same time.  Would the best way to handle this be this way?  Where I sleep the write process should we hit the throttle?  Or should I be doing something to avoid the throttle completely.  In fact, is my code even doing what I think it is, which is retrying the data after waiting a second?

```
try{
   amazonDynamoAsyncDb.updateItemAsync(updateRequest)
   }catch{
     case e: ThrottlingException => {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        //retry here, but how?
        }
   }
```

Comment: Actually, I may just have learned that it auto retries on it's own.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: What you need may be a scheduler, are you familiar with Akka? You can create an actor doing this, if the attempt fails the actor sends a message to itself in 1 second reminding itself to try again. Or you can just use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/9414163), namely the `retry` pattern.

Comment: I am not familiar, but I have heard of Akka.  I will look into those two options.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK for Java will retry throttled requests 10 times by default, before throwing a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException. If your items are small (1KB or less) and you are performing the writes from EC2 in the same region as your table you can assume each write will take around 10 ms. That means each thread of processing can do about 100 writes per second. To scale your writes to 3000 writes per second, you would need 30 threads and 30 HTTP connections. 3000 small (1kb) writes per second translates to a data throughput of 2.92 MB per second. Thus, for this write load, it does not appear that EC2 hardware could become a bottleneck. I recommend you do some measurements to figure out how long it takes to write each of your items on average, and scale your threads and HTTP connections appropriately.